# Is there a way to document AVRO schema for GCP pubsub

Tags: google-cloud-platform, openapi, avro, google-cloud-pubsub, asyncapi

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XoYno.png)Like openAPI is there a way to document AVRO schema for GCP pubsub. Is there an UI provided by GCP like swagger UI. Or what is the recomendation here.

According to me Async API could be an option. But really not sure what is the best solution

Comment: What do you mean by "document AVRO schema"? Add documentation within the schema? Make publishers and subscribers aware of which schema is tied to a topic? And to which async API are you referring?

Comment: Yes adding doscumentation within the schema to understand more about the schema (topic assosciation , meta data). Kind of simmilar when we expose an API as rest we will add the documentation . Is there a avro schema registry available to check the number of schemas we have and the mapping between the schemas and the topics

Comment: https://javro.github.io/

Comment: https://hackolade.com/nosqldb/avro-schema-editor.html

Comment: https://www.altova.com/xmlspy-xml-editor/avro_tools

Comment: https://github.com/Talend/avro-schema-editor

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use AsyncAPI for it as it's protocol agnostic, ontop of enabling you to define payloads with Avro.

Here is an example with the new AsyncAPI v3 specification:

```yaml
asyncapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Example with Avro and GCP pubsub
  version: 0.1.0
channels:
  example:
    address: my-topic
    messages:
      myAvroMessage:
        payload:
          schemaFormat: application/vnd.apache.avro;version=1.9.0
          schema:
            type: record
            name: User
            namespace: com.company
            doc: User information
            fields:
              - name: displayName
                type: string
              - name: email
                type: string
              - name: age
                type: int
operations:
  example.publish:
    action: receive
    channel:
      $ref: '#/channels/example'
    messages:
      - $ref: '#/channels/example/messages/myAvroMessage'
```

[Also check it out in studio for a HTML preview](https://studio.asyncapi.com/?base64=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).

If you need to define explicit Google PubSub information, you use the concept called [Bindings](https://www.asyncapi.com/docs/reference/specification/v3.0.0#definitionsBindings), that can be defined on channels, operations and messages.

[Check it out in Studio here](https://studio.asyncapi.com/?base64=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%3D). Here is just a simple example with the example above with an example Google PubSub binding information.

```yaml
asyncapi: 3.0.0
info:
  title: Example with Avro and GCP pubsub
  version: 0.1.0
channels:
  example:
    address: my-topic
    messages:
      myAvroMessage:
        payload:
          schemaFormat: application/vnd.apache.avro;version=1.9.0
          schema:
            type: record
            name: User
            namespace: com.company
            doc: User information
            fields:
              - name: displayName
                type: string
              - name: email
                type: string
              - name: age
                type: int
    bindings:
      googlepubsub:
        messageRetentionDuration: 86400s
        messageStoragePolicy:
          allowedPersistenceRegions:
          - us-central1
          - us-central2
          - us-east1
          - us-east4
          - us-east5
          - us-east7
          - us-south1
          - us-west1
          - us-west2
          - us-west3
          - us-west4
        schemaSettings:
          encoding: binary
          name: projects/your-project/schemas/message-proto
operations:
  example.publish:
    action: receive
    channel:
      $ref: '#/channels/example'
    messages:
      - $ref: '#/channels/example/messages/myAvroMessage'
```

[Checkout all the documentation and examples for Google pubsub here](https://github.com/asyncapi/bindings/tree/master/googlepubsub).